# Is there a way to label multiple 3d surfaces in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I attempt to solve a non-linear mathematical optimization problem with linear constraints. For this, I'm trying to visualize the constraints in 3d to see what is happening and why I get a feasible solutions for some parameters in the constraints and not others.

In order to achieve this, I want to use **matplotlib** from python to generate 3d surfaces (planes since all my constraints are linear).

However, without in-plot labeling, it is very difficult to identify which surface belongs to which constraint. This led me to want to look for a way to add a legend with colors inside the plot.

I recognize that there is already a way to do this in 2D, inside the method `ax.plot()` or `ax.scatter()`, but trying to do the same didn't work with `ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, label = 'mylabel')`

The full script is below :

```py
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

plt.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10


# First constraint
g2 = np.linspace(-5,5,2)
g3 = np.linspace(-5,5,2)
G2,G3 = np.meshgrid(g2,g3)
G4_1 = -1.18301270189222 - 0.5*G2 + 0.5*G3
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
c1 = ax.plot_surface(G2, G3, G4_1, label = "c1")

# Second
G3, G4 = np.meshgrid(g2, g3)
G2 = G3
c2 = ax.plot_surface(G2, G3, G4, label = "c2")

# Third
G2,G3 = np.meshgrid(g2,g3)
G4 = (0.408248290463863*G2 + 0.408248290463863*G3 -0.707106781186548)/1.63299316185545
c3 = ax.plot_surface(G2, G3, G4, label = "c3")

# And forth
G4 = (1.04903810567666 - (0.288675134594813*G2 + 0.288675134594813*G3))/0.577350269189626
c4 = ax.plot_surface(G2, G3, G4, label="c4")



ax.legend() # -> error : 'AttributeError: 'Poly3DCollection' object has no attribute '_edgecolors2d''


# labeling the figure
fig.suptitle("Constraints")
#plt.xlabel('g2', fontsize=14)
#plt.ylabel('g3', fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$g_2$', fontsize=15, rotation=60)
ax.set_ylabel('$g_3$', fontsize=15, rotation=60)
ax.set_zlabel('$g_4$', fontsize=15, rotation=60)
plt.savefig('Constraints.jpg')
plt.show()
```

Which results in the following figure.

[image: plot]

As you might have seen, there is no way to tell which surface belongs to which constraint, and what I want to achieve is a legend, like [here](https://pythonspot.com/3d-scatterplot/).

I read through the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449109/adding-legend-to-a-surface-plot), but it didn't work here since I have multiple surfaces. After trying it, it keeps showing only one label, not four.

So my question is, is there a way to add a legend to my `ax.plot_surface` or any other suitable hack?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There you go.

The solution was in this error here: `ax.legend() # -> error : 'AttributeError: 'Poly3DCollection' object has no attribute '_edgecolors2d''`.
I believe it's a bug.

If you explore any of your surface objects (let say `c1`) you can see that they have the attribute `'_edgecolors3d'`, which is what should be called when creating the legend.

So we simply create a new attribute named `'_edgecolors2d'` with the same content as `'_edgecolors3d'`.

Once the `'_edgecolors2d'` problem is solved you will encounter a new one with `'_facecolors2d'`. We repeat the same procedure and we are done.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

plt.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10


# First constraint
g2 = np.linspace(-5,5,2)
g3 = np.linspace(-5,5,2)
G2,G3 = np.meshgrid(g2,g3)
G4_1 = -1.18301270189222 - 0.5*G2 + 0.5*G3
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
c1 = ax.plot_surface(G2, G3, G4_1, label = "c1")
c1._facecolors2d=c1._facecolors3d
c1._edgecolors2d=c1._edgecolors3d

# Second
G3, G4 = np.meshgrid(g2, g3)
G2 = G3
c2 = ax.plot_surface(G2, G3, G4, label = "c2")
c2._facecolors2d=c2._facecolors3d
c2._edgecolors2d=c2._edgecolors3d

# Third
G2,G3 = np.meshgrid(g2,g3)
G4 = (0.408248290463863*G2 + 0.408248290463863*G3 -0.707106781186548)/1.63299316185545
c3 = ax.plot_surface(G2, G3, G4, label = "c3")
c3._facecolors2d=c3._facecolors3d
c3._edgecolors2d=c3._edgecolors3d

# And forth
G4 = (1.04903810567666 - (0.288675134594813*G2 + 0.288675134594813*G3))/0.577350269189626
c4 = ax.plot_surface(G2, G3, G4, label="c4")

c4._facecolors2d=c4._facecolors3d
c4._edgecolors2d=c4._edgecolors3d

ax.legend() # -> error : 'AttributeError: 'Poly3DCollection' object has no attribute '_edgecolors2d''


# labeling the figure
fig.suptitle("Constraints")
#plt.xlabel('g2', fontsize=14)
#plt.ylabel('g3', fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$g_2$', fontsize=15, rotation=60)
ax.set_ylabel('$g_3$', fontsize=15, rotation=60)
ax.set_zlabel('$g_4$', fontsize=15, rotation=60)
plt.savefig('Constraints.jpg')
plt.show()
```

[image: output]

Comment: It's [this issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4067) which must have been forgotten somehow.

Answer (score 8):

This is an update to [@Gio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55534939/3284713). As of `matplotlib 3.3.3`, `_facecolors3d` and `_edgecolors3d` do not exist. So, instead of this:

```
c1._facecolors2d = c1._facecolors3d
c1._edgecolors2d = c1._edgecolors3d
```

that would lead to a similar `AttributeError`, try this:

```
c1._facecolors2d = c1._facecolor3d
c1._edgecolors2d = c1._edgecolor3d
```

I had to make this an answer, instead of a comment, due to low rep.